# PageReference.setRedirect() is not working

Tags: salesforce

Hi i am trying to redirecting visualforce page to google.com page 
here is my VF code

```
<apex:page controller="google_redir">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton action="{! hello1}"  value="Save New Account Value"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and here is my apex controller code

```
public class google_redir{


public PageReference hello1(){
PageReference reference=new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
reference.setRedirect(true);

return reference;
}
}
```

page not redirected to google.com it shows a blank page.
please help me in correcting the error where i am wrong why it is not redirecting to google.com page.

Comment: SFDC redirects actually use a client-side redirect via JS, so if JS is disabled or has restrictions against cross-domain redirects, that "blank page" is what you will see. View the source of it and check if what it's trying to do is indeed getting swallowed by your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact code you posted is working for me. I was redirected to `http://www.google.com` after clicking the `Save New Account Value` button. I modified your code slightly after testing, though, for readability:

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="google_redir">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!hello1}"  value="Save New Account Value"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class google_redir {
    public PageReference hello1() {
        PageReference reference=new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
        reference.setRedirect(true);
        return reference;
    }
}
```

Could it be an issue with your browser or your Internet connection? Try redirecting to a different URL like `http://www.salesforce.com` or using a different Internet browser, just to see if that works.

Comment: +1 that this code should be working as written. However, setting a redirect is redundant when it's a VF page with another controller and especially when it's a full URL to another domain. "Note that if the URL of the PageReference object is set
to a website outside of the salesforce.com domain,
or to a page with a different controller or controller
extension, the redirect always occurs, regardless of
whether the redirect attribute is set to true or
false."

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when trying to switch to a standard Visualforce page.  I took the code directly from [the tutorial](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm) and like Ritesh I got a blank page.

Code:

```
public PageReference save() {
        // Add the account to the database.  
    
        insert account;
        // Send the user to the detail page for the new account. 
    
        PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(account).view();
        acctPage.setRedirect(true);
        return acctPage;
    }
```

I found the solution by watching the results in FireBug (Firefox).   The problem was caused by a permission denied error.  Once I disabled Development Mode the page redirect worked fine.

I hope this alternative variation of the problem and its solution will help someone someday.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem. Strange however. It has been working for quite some time and suddenly it is a problem that I have development mode enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this has been answered but just wanted to add that you dont need to set the redirect to true in this case.  That is only if you want to keep the view state.  If you are leaving Salesforce then there is no view state to maintain.

```
return new PageReference('http://yrt.ca/');
```

Answer (score -1):

We need to use following code syntax to navigate to external urls
PageReference reference=new PageReference('External Url');.

Go through an example in the link[PageReference Example](http://salesforceglobe4u.blogspot.in/2016/07/pagereference-in-salesforce.html)